# An efficient way to write this piece of code

Tags: c#, performance

How would a experienced programmer write this...

```
SummonerPlatform = (SummonerRegion == Region.br) ? SummonerPlatform = Platform.BR1 : (SummonerRegion == Region.eune) ? SummonerPlatform = Platform.EUN1 :
                                (SummonerRegion == Region.euw) ? SummonerPlatform = Platform.EUW1 : (SummonerRegion == Region.kr) ? SummonerPlatform = Platform.KR :
                                (SummonerRegion == Region.lan) ? SummonerPlatform = Platform.LA1 : (SummonerRegion == Region.las) ? SummonerPlatform = Platform.LA2 :
                                (SummonerRegion == Region.na) ? SummonerPlatform = Platform.NA1 : (SummonerRegion == Region.oce) ? SummonerPlatform = Platform.OC1 :
                                (SummonerRegion == Region.ru) ? SummonerPlatform = Platform.RU : (SummonerRegion == Region.tr) ? SummonerPlatform = Platform.TR1 : SummonerPlatform = Platform.EUW1;
```

Comment: Would be better in [CodeReview.SE]?

Comment: Is `Region` an enum? If not is `Region.br` etc. a constant?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Please provide more context surrounding this piece of code if posting it on Code Review. Code Review does not like code that has been stripped of context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either use switch() statement like this:

```
 switch (SummonerRegion)
            {
                case Region.br:
                    SummonerPlatform = Platform.BR1;
                    break;
                case Region.eune:
                    SummonerPlatform = Platform.EUN1;
                    break;
                case ...
            }
```

or create a mapping like this:

```
static Dictionary<Region, Platform> Mapping = new Dictionary<Region, Platform> { 
  {Region.br, Platform.BR1}, 
  {Region.eune, Platform.EUN1}, 
  ...
};
```

and then use it in your code like this:

```
SummonerPlatform=Mapping[SummonerRegion];
```

The switch() approach will work only if the Region is enumeration. If not, use the second approach